# Synaptics Touchpad Driver crashes occasionally when using multitouch

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, touchpad, thinkpad

I'm using a Lenovo Thinkpad w520 running Windows 10 (upgrade from Windows 7, not full re-install, btw). Like other thinkpads, it has a touchpad from Synaptics.

Occasionally, and only when performing two-fingered scrolling on the touchpad, Windows will crash and the BSOD will indicate that a driver called SynTP.sys was to blame.

For the first almost 4 years I had this machine (same windows install), this issue never came up. This SynTP.sys BSOD started occurring in ~December, having upgraded to Windows 10 in August.

I thought it might have something to do with Windows 10:

- Driver incompatibility with Windows 10?
- New version of driver (that Windows 10 upgraded to) has a bug?
- Driver is fine but hardware has developed a glitch that trips driver?

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you installed the current version of the Synaptics drivers?

Comment: @Ramhound I've installed the latest version of the drivers from Synaptics' website. v19.0.19.1, 08/2015. I think this was the version I already had from Lenovo. It could take some time to determine if this has worked as the problem occurs unpredictably.